# Jquery replace a specific character combination

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I can't figure out why my jquery replacement code wouldn't work.

I try to make the follow replacement:

```
http://mysite.com/_thumbs/0000312/0312718/0312718_$varm.jpg
```

I added '$var' to the position where I want to put a number, we can take '1' for now.
So I need to replace $var for 1.

What I tried;

```
 var img = $('img', this).attr('src'); // I grabs the image url like above.
 img.replace(/$var/, 1)
```

But nothing happens.

Thanks in advance!

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dollar sign is a special character in regular expressions.

```
img.replace(/\$var/, "1");
```

Escaping the `$` with a backslash will tell JavaScript that you want it to match a dollar sign. Otherwise, `$` means "match the end of the search string".

*edit* — also note that if you want the updated string you'll need to save the return value from calling `.replace()`:

```
img = img.replace(/\$var/, "1");
```

(You can of course save the replacement results in a different variable.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this zupa dupa fast answer! I will accept it when I can :)

Comment: Oh and also, the `.replace()` function returns the value but doesn't change the original string; I'll update the answer @Freshtea .